# Why did Mohammed Morsi get thrown out of office

Tags: egypt

What made the Egyptian Military want to throw Mohammed Morsi out of office.

Comment: this is the real reason this corrupt generals and bureaucrats were against him
watch Egypt lost power on aljazeera http://webapps.aljazeera.net/aje/custom/2014/egyptlostpower/index.html#opening

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The official reason is that he conspired with Hamas to set fire to a prison, kidnap and kill officers/soldiers/prison guards in 2011 when he broke out of prison.**

The [Alantic Wire reported](http://www.theatlanticwire.com/global/2013/07/mohammed-morsi-detained-egypt-braces-more-protests/67632/) that:

> a government prosecutor has ordered that ousted President Mohamed Morsi be detained for 15 days, on accusations that he collaborated with terrorists to kill police officers and soldiers. The charges stem from Morsi's 2011 prison break after he was arrested during protests against then-President Hosni Mubarak. He is accused of conspiring with members of the Palestinian militant group Hamas to set fire to the prison, kidnapping police officers and soldiers, and killing some guards and other prisoners.

The [BBC reported](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-23464036) that:

> The order issued on Friday is the first official statement on Mr Morsi's judicial status since he was overthrown.

Morsi was being held since July 3, and although not official statements, one of the generals, [Abdul-Fattah el-Sisi](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/04/world/middleeast/egypt.html?pagewanted=all) said

> The generals built their case for intervention in a carefully orchestrated series of maneuvers, calling their actions an effort at a “**national reconciliation**” and refusing to call their takeover a coup. At a televised news conference late on Wednesday night, Gen. Abdul-Fattah el-Sisi said that the military had no interest in politics and was ousting Mr. Morsi because he had failed to fulfill “**the hope for a national consensus**.”

Comment: This is correct but doesn't answer the "What made the Egyptian Military want" part in the body. This is just the official justification. Granted, answering THAT question well requires a pretty deep answer on Egyptian and Arab politics that would take 10 hours to write and take a couple of pages, so I am too chicken to try though I know the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Morsi and his 'Freedom and Justice Party' (Muslim Brotherhood) were democratically elected to power, his anti-democratic behaviour and policies as president caused civil unrest and public disenchantment which led to the June 2013 Egyptian protests and ultimately a military-led coup soon after.  There certainly are other motives involved but the below demonstrates the undemocratic nature and major issues of his presidency  which facilitated the military intervention with the backing of many Egyptians.

- As president, Morsi altered the constitution granting him enough power to counteract any move from the Mubarak-era judges in the Supreme Court.
- Freedom and Justice Party are an Islamist Party with very strong links to the Muslim Brotherhood.
- Established an Islamist-dominated Constitutional Assembly which many deemed "an Islamist Coup"
- Prosecution of Journalists and demonstrators. Morsi's Government issued an arrest warrant for Ahmed Shafik (opposition leader)
- On 22nd December his Constitution was approved in a national by 64%. Opponents claimed fraud and called for an inquiry never granted.
- 2012/13 Egyptian protests attracted millions of protestors. Dozens of deaths & hundreds of injuries.
- Many of Morsi's advisors resigned and judges spoke out against his illegal actions.
- Finally led to a coup compromised of the military, opposition leader, Grand Imam of Al Azhar and the Coptic Pope.